# Two different ways to choose specific ABI in Android

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, arm64, abi

I am using `CMake` to use JNI in my current Android project. To keep my apk size small, I want to support only `arm64-v8a`. I found that there are two ways to do it:

(1) Set the option inside `Cmake` block

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.something.here"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
}
```

(2) Set the option inside `ndk` block

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.something.here"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
    }
    ndk {
        abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
    }
}
```

They both create working APKs. But I'm curious about three things.

1. I am using only `CMake` for JNI. Why setting inside `ndk` block (option 2) works?
2. The apks are different in size. Option 1 generated 15.0 MB while option 2 generated 12.3 MB. Why is that?
3. Are there any speed or performance difference between the apks generated by the two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using only CMake for JNI. Why setting inside ndk block (option 2) works?

`ndk` is not the same thing as `externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild`.

> The apks are different in size. Option 1 generated 15.0 MB while option 2 generated 12.3 MB. Why is that?

- `ndk { abiFilters` specifies which ABIs gradle should build for and package into your APK.
- `externalNativeBuild { **** { abiFilters` only specifies which ABIs gradle should build for (so you could potentially build for ABIs that you don't actually include in your APK, if you want that for some reason).

It's difficult to say why there's a size difference, because we're not sitting at your development machine. But one plausible explanation is that you had some existing library for another ABI in your project directory. Then when you removed `ndk { abiFilters` you told gradle that it's fine to also package that older library into your APK, thereby increasing the APK's size.

> Are there any speed or performance difference between the apks generated by the two options?

If you mean runtime speed differences, then I see none. There could be differences in build time and installation time depending on how much you build and how much you package into the APK.